# Can I decode data with base64 in php which was encoded in java?

Tags: java, php

I have this java code I used to encode a serialized object that contains a couple of strings in base64

```
public static String encode(Object obj) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
    o.writeObject(obj);
    return Base64.encodeToString(b.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

I store the resultant string in database using PHP ... I know how to decode this in java but for some reasons I need to do it in the PHP code ... so how to do it in PHP ?

Comment: PHP has `base64_decode` http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 is an encoding scheme, so it doesn't matter which language you use when you encode or decode.

```
 <?php
    $str = 'VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==';//your base64 encoded string
    echo base64_decode($str);
 ?>
```